# Are Active Directory Users and Computers permissions different then Active Directory Administrative Center?

Tags: active-directory

I just delegated control to a helpdesk user in Active Directory Users and Computers to be able to unlock accounts and reset passwords.  This functionality works good in ADUC but doesn't work in ADAC, it tells her she doesn't have sufficient rights.

How do I give her rights in ADAC?

Comment: See if this Microsoft support article applies to you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2577917/unlocking-a-user-account-fails-when-using-adac-or-the-unlock-adaccount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a know issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2577917/unlocking-a-user-account-fails-when-using-adac-or-the-unlock-adaccount). Microsoft provides a hotfix and a workaround:

- Grant the "Read account restrictions" and "Write account restrictions" permissions to the user account.

> Granting the "Read account restrictions" and "Write account
>   restrictions" permissions to the user account will enable the user
>   account to perform account configurations that may affect the security
>   of the account and of the domain.

Comment: Thank you!  I did search and couldn't find anything on it.  That makes a lot more sense.  I appreciate you taking the time to provide the article.